# Shopify Styling

Tags: css, sass, shopify

Is there any way to get page identifier in css in shopify.

I want to do styling work in shopify specific page not all the pages.

So I want to specify pages, either homepage or pages I've built, blog page or shopping page etc.

Answer (score 15):

You can use something like this:

Replace `<body>` in **theme.liquid** with the below one:

```
<body class="{{ template }} {{ page.handle }}{% if template == 'collection' %}{{ collection.handle }}{% endif %}{% if template == 'product' %}{{ product.title | handleize }}{% endif %}{% if template == 'blog' %}{{ blog.handle }}{% endif %}{% if template == 'article' %}{{ article.title | handleize  }}{% endif %}">
```

To add a class to the body element of the page.

To break it down, here is what I'm doing:

`{{ template }}`

this return the name of the template ( for example index for the home page, blog for the blog page, collection for the shop page an so on )

`{{ page.handle }}`

returns the handle of each unique page ( about-us, contact-us... only pages and not collection, blogs, products )

`{% if template == 'collection' %}{{ collection.handle }}{% endif %}{% if template == 'product' %}{{ product.title | handleize }}{% endif %}`

Here I'm checking if the page is collection `{% if template == 'collection' %}` and if the page is a product `{% if template == 'product' %}` and adding the handle for the collection `{{ collection.handle }}` and the title to the product page with a handleize filter `{{ product.title | handleize }}`. I check the page since the product doesn't return a handle the normal way and I'm using the title instead and if I don't check the collection it will add it to the product page as well.

`{% if template == 'blog' %}{{ blog.handle }}{% endif %}{% if template == 'article' %}{{ article.title | handleize  }}{% endif %}`

This one logic is the same as the collection/product one.

And once you set the above, you can target the body class for each page and style it that way.

Comment: Well written answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a new page template on Shopify. then you can customise as need. when finish you can select the page template via shopify admin panel.

**Create alternate template for pages.**
From your Shopify admin, click Online Store, and then click Themes

Find the theme you want to edit, click the ... button, and then click Edit HTML/CSS.

Under the Template folder, click the Add a new template link.

Choose the appropriate option for your new template (page or product, etc), and give your template a meaningful name (for example, page.no-sidebar).

Edit and save your new template as you normally would.

Once your alternate template has been created it will appear in a Template drop-down. So, if you created an alternate template for products, you will see the option to select a template in a new Template section at the bottom of every product page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can identify the pages through class. In the shopify we have different template for all pages, home page, product page, collection page, cart page, blog page.. 
If you goto the  tag you can find the class name template-name something.Its easy to identify the page and you will be able to apply the css for particular pages

or you can apply the liquid code in the template header section. You just need to add this line in your theme.liquid file where is the body tag

```
 <body class="boyd test {{ template.name }}">
```

I hope that will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Every Shopify page having its own unique id, It just similar to the below

```
<body id="home-page" class="template-index" data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" style="overflow: visible; height: auto;">
```

So if you want to add any style, You can call the unique id for the particular page before the id/class you want to make any change.

For example, if you want to give background-color to class "a", the CSS be like

```
#home-page .a
{
background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it works for me:-

```
{% unless template == 'index'  %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'magnific-popup.min.css' | asset_url }}" type="text/css" defer/>
{% endunless %}

<link href="{{ 'base.css' | asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" defer>
<link href="{{ 'slick.css' | asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" defer>
<link href="{{ 'slick-theme.css' | asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" defer>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'common.scss.css' | asset_url }}" defer>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'index.scss.css' | asset_url }}" defer>

{% if template == 'collection' or template == 'search' or template == 'list-collections'  %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'collection-page.scss.css' | asset_url }}" defer>
{% endif %}
{% if template == 'cart'  %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'cart-page.scss.css' | asset_url }}" defer>
{% endif %}
{% if template == 'blog' or template == 'article' %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'blog_page.scss.css' | asset_url }}" defer>
{% endif %}
{% if template == 'page' or template == 'page.special-events' or template == 'page.prom-dresses' or template == 'page.evening-dresses' or template == 'page.homecoming-dresses' or template == 'page.wedding-dresses' or template == 'page.all-dresses' or template == 'page.careers' or template == 'page.contact' or template == 'page.meet_the_team' or template == 'page.about-us' or template == 'page.store-location' or template == 'page.shop-by-style' or template == 'page.shop-by-color' or template == 'article.careers' or template == 'article.stores' %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'content_pages.scss.css' | asset_url }}" defer>
{% endif %}
```